# GROUP_CONCAT Performance issue with distinct and sub_query

Tags: mysql, performance, join, distinct, group-concat

I am trying to execute this query in MYSQL DB.

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName
    CONCAT(COALESCE(Address1, ''),
    COALESCE(Address2, '')) AS Address2,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(EmpDept ' ') FROM EMP_DEPT
     USE INDEX (EMP_DEPT_IDX)
     WHERE EMP_DEPT.EMP_ID = EMP.EMP_ID) AS DEPT,
    COUNT(PIN) AS PIN,
    MIN(SALARY) AS SALARY,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PAY_CODE SEPARATOR ' ') AS PAYROLL_CODE
FROM EMP WHERE HOUSE='YELLOW' AND HOUSE_AREA='220'
    AND (JOIN_YEAR = '2011' OR JOIN_YEAR = '2012')
    AND EMP_BAND='G'
    AND (FRESHER = 'N' OR FRESHER = 'FALSE')   
    AND PIN IS NOT NULL
    AND SALARY > 0
GROUP BY FirstName,LastName Address3, Address2, DEPT
```

The query is working fine and I am getting the required resultset.

Only the problem is, there is huge performance hit on these two lines of code , written using GROUP_CONCAT,

```
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(EmpDept ' ') FROM EMP_DEPT
    USE INDEX (EMP_DEPT_IDX)
    WHERE EMP_DEPT.EMP_ID = EMP.EMP_ID) AS DEPT


 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PAY_CODE SEPARATOR ' ') AS PAYROLL_CODE
```

I tried adding INDEX, but still no luck.(only these sub queries are taking around 30-40sec to execute)

I tried implementing Joins, but as i am new to mysql there is no luck..

Can anyone help me in making my query execute faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the correlated subquery with an outer join with a subquery:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName
    CONCAT(COALESCE(Address1, ''),
    COALESCE(Address2, '')) AS Address2,
    COALESCE(DEPT, '') AS DEPT,
    COUNT(PIN) AS PIN,
    MIN(SALARY) AS SALARY,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PAY_CODE SEPARATOR ' ') AS PAYROLL_CODE
FROM EMP 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EMP_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(EmpDept SEPARATOR ' ') AS DEPT
           FROM EMP_DEPT
           GROUP BY EMP_ID) AS EMP_DEPT ON EMP_DEPT.EMP_ID = EMP.EMP_ID
WHERE HOUSE='YELLOW' AND HOUSE_AREA='220'
    AND (JOIN_YEAR = '2011' OR JOIN_YEAR = '2012')
    AND EMP_BAND='G'
    AND (FRESHER = 'N' OR FRESHER = 'FALSE')   
    AND PIN IS NOT NULL
    AND SALARY > 0
GROUP BY EMP.EMP_ID
```

Also, I changed the final `GROUP BY` to use the `EMP_ID` column, not the returned column values.

It's also possible that just changing the final `GROUP BY` will solve your problem. Grouping by an indexed column should be more efficient, so make sure you have an index on `EMP_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

The best index for that subquery is `EMP_DEPT(EMPT_ID, EmpDept)`.  Is that the index you have defined?

The second `group_concat()` cannot take advantage of an index.

If you remove these two lines, how much faster is the query?